# Доступ к локальному адресу через прокси

Tags: linux, ubuntu, proxy

На ubuntu 16.04 доступ в интернет осуществляется через прокси

```
http_proxy="http://username:password@ip:port/"
https_proxy="http://username:password@ip:port/"
ftp_proxy="http://username:password@ip:port/"
socks_proxy="http://username:password@ip:port/"
```

Когда я в браузере хочу загрузить страницу по локальному адресу `127.0.0.1:1947`
вылетает ошибка **Access Denied**. Если убрать прокси то страница становиться доступной.

Есть ли возможность настроить соединение так, чтобы доступ к локальному адресу не осуществлялся через прокси.

Comment: Установить в браузере исключение - не использовать прокси для адреса 127.0.0.1

Comment: по идее, `export no_proxy="localhost, 127.0.0.1 …"`, дал бы ответом, но сам не проверял, ибо не использую общесистемные настройки....

Comment: Настройте правильно файервол.